# Rail, duplicate posting with form_for from another model view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First, I have some issue with using form_for from another models view the way every seems to say it works. ie." from 'character/index.html.erb' form_for(@character, @statistic) do ...."
Yeah that method looks simple enough and I'd love to use it but it wont work for me so apparently im doing "IT" wrong. Below is my current setup and issue. Firstly using form_for is a nightmare to get to work and second but more importantly, whenever i click submit on my form it makes duplicate posts somehow.

events_controller.rb

```
...
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @message = @event.messages.build
    @locations = Location.all
    @city = Location.find_by_city(params[:city])
    @messages = @event.messages.limit(5).order('created_at DESC')
  end 
...
```

Messages_controller.rb

```
...
  def create
    @message = Message.create(params[:message])
    @message.event_id = params[:event_id]
    @message.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {@message}
    end
  end
...
```

events/show.html.erb

```
...
      <%= form_for([@event, @message], :remote => true) do |f|%>
    <%= f.text_field :msg %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => current_requester.name %>
    <%= f.submit "send"%>
      <% end %>
...
```

In case you are wondering, the js response is and works fine to update the div i pointed it at.

Development.log

> Started POST "/events/4/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jan 22 18:19:57
>   -0600 2012   Processing by MessagesController#create as JS   Parameters: {"commit"=>"send", "event_id"=>"4",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"OjW6XyzwCbCgXfu74Qy1VYjJm5+YGIjw9f+yH+2pi04=",
>   "utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"name"=>"Chris", "msg"=>"fd"}}   SQL
>   (0.1ms)  BEGIN   SQL (0.5ms)  describe `messages`   AREL (0.2ms) 
>   INSERT INTO `messages` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`,
>   `event_id`, `msg`) VALUES ('2012-01-23 00:19:57', 'Chris', '2012-01-23
>   00:19:57', NULL, 'fd')   SQL (85.4ms)  COMMIT   SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>   AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `messages` SET `updated_at` = '2012-01-23
>   00:19:57', `event_id` = 4 WHERE `messages`.`id` = 25   SQL (89.6ms) 
>   COMMIT Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (0.2ms) Rendered
>   messages/create.js.erb (1.4ms) Completed 200 OK in 198ms (Views: 8.6ms
>   | ActiveRecord: 176.5ms)
>
> Started POST "/events/4/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jan 22 18:19:57
>   -0600 2012   Processing by MessagesController#create as JS   Parameters: {"event_id"=>"4",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"OjW6XyzwCbCgXfu74Qy1VYjJm5+YGIjw9f+yH+2pi04=",
>   "utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"name"=>"Chris", "msg"=>"fd"}}   SQL
>   (0.1ms)  BEGIN   SQL (0.3ms)  describe `messages`   AREL (0.2ms) 
>   INSERT INTO `messages` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `event_id`, `msg`,
>   `name`) VALUES ('2012-01-23 00:19:57', '2012-01-23 00:19:57', NULL,
>   'fd', 'Chris')   SQL (89.6ms)  COMMIT   SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN   AREL
>   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `messages` SET `updated_at` = '2012-01-23 00:19:57',
>   `event_id` = 4 WHERE `messages`.`id` = 26   SQL (64.0ms)  COMMIT
>   Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (0.2ms) Rendered
>   messages/create.js.erb (1.2ms) Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 7.1ms
>   | ActiveRecord: 154.6ms)
>   n0de@IbeSuperMadtron:~/workspace/RadioMint/log$

Adding in the models, in case someone asks.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Geocode

  belongs_to :disk_jockey
  belongs_to :venue

  has_many :song_requests
  has_many :fresh_song_requests, :conditions => "played = false", :class_name => "SongRequest"
  has_many :requested_songs, :through => :song_requests, :source => 'song', :order => 'songs.created_at ASC'
  has_one :poll
  has_many :messages
  has_many :event_playlists
  has_many :playlists, :through => :event_playlists

  # I havent figured out the issue as to why messages dont show up when a validation is not met
  # I have used the ':message => "" ' tailed to the end of these validations but they never show up.
  validates_presence_of :name, :disk_jockey_id
  validates :code, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to make it a `form_for` with `@event`. I assume you just want it to be a form to create a message for a particular event? Just make it:

```
<%= form_for @message, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

You already declared `@message` to be associated with `@event` through the assignment, so unless you have input fields for the attributes of `@event`, you don't need to include `@event` in the `form_for`.

---

But if you really do need input for event data, instead of using the two models in the `form_for`, perhaps you could try the following alternative approach. In your `events.rb` model file, add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
```

Then in your view, do something like this:

```
<%= form_for([@event, @message], :remote => true) do |f|%>
  <%= f.fields_for :message do |m| %>
    <%= m.text_field :message_field %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```